# Page of latest posts in orchard

Tags: c#, blogs, orchardcms, customizing

I have two blogs on my orchard cms site, "news" and "blog".
I'd need a page where to show the list of latest blog posts for each blog, eg:
www.mysite.com/news
www.mysite.com/blog

I've only found a way to list blog posts in a widget, but I'd need a page devoted to that.

I've tried to create a layer, filtered by url,  for that and put the latestblogposts widget on the content for that page, but to no avail, because simply the page does not exist.

I've tried to create a Page but I can only put content in it.

there must be a simple, standard way to do it but I cannot find it.
thanks.

Comment: How is what you're trying to do different from a simple blog page? What I mean by this is that whenever you create a blog ("news" or "blog" in your case), that blog gets unique *slug*. Navigating to URL with that slug, you're shown with the latest blog posts of that blog..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a query and a projection page.